# RavenDB: Field Not Indexed Exception

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

When I try to query a document using a field within it that I have tried to index then RavenDB complains that it is not in fact indexed.

The document - "jobs/332" - is as follows:

```
{
    "Type": "Outbound",
    "Flight": {
        "Operator": "SAS",
        "Number": "267",
        "Origin": "MAN",
        "Gate": "019",
        "Stand": "A12",
        "STD": "2015-08-20T09:15:00.0000000Z",
        "ETD": "2015-08-20T09:16:00.0000000Z",
        "Status": "On Time",
        "Seat": "16F"
    },
    "PAX": {
        "Name": "Mr. John Smith",
        "Types": [
            {
                "Description": "WCHC"
            },
            {
                "Description": "DPNA"
            }
        ],
        "Prenotified": true
    },
    "Stages": [
        {
            "AssignedAgents": [
                {
                    "Id": 34,
                    "Name": "Derek Brown"
                }
            ],
            "StageStart": {
                "Location": "T1 Checkin",
                "Time": "2015-08-20T08:00:00.0000000Z"
            },
            "StageEnd": {
                "Location": "Lounge 1",
                "Time": "2015-08-20T08:25:00.0000000Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "AssignedAgents": null,
            "StageStart": {
                "Location": "Lounge 1",
                "Time": "2015-08-20T08:45:00.0000000Z"
            },
            "StageEnd": {
                "Location": "Gate 019",
                "Time": "2015-08-20T08:55:00.0000000Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created the following static index:

```
public class Job_Agent : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Job>
{
    public Job_Agent()
    {
        Map = jobs =>   from job in jobs
                        from stage in job.Stages
                        from agent in stage.AssignedAgents
                        select new
                        {
                            agent.Id
                        };
    }
}
```

When I try to query the document with the following query:

```
_session.Query<Job, Job_Agent>()
                     .First(u => u.Stages
                        .Any(t => t.AssignedAgents
                            .Any(a => a.Id == 34)));
```

Then I get the following message:

```
The field 'Stages_AssignedAgents_Id' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on where I have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You index should be specified like so:

```
from job in docs.Jobs
select new
{
  Stages_AssignedAgents_Id = job.Stages.SelectMany(x=>x.AssignedAgents).Select(x=>x.Id)
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks, Oren.